# Segmentation fault in C in Caesar cipher algorithm

Tags: c, cs50

Trying to solve for CS50's Ceasar solution.
I'm getting a segmentation fault error.

More formally, Caesar’s algorithm (i.e., cipher) encrypts messages by “rotating” each letter by k positions. More formally, if p is some plaintext (i.e., an unencrypted message), `pi` is the i-th character in p, and `k` is a secret key (i.e., a non-negative integer), then each letter, `ci`, in the ciphertext, c, is computed as

```
ci = (pi + k) % 26
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

string cipher(string ptext, int k);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        string ptext = NULL;
        string ctext = NULL;

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ptext = get_string("Text:");
                int k = atoi(argv[1]);
                ctext = cipher(ptext, k);
            }
        }

        printf("Plain Text: %s \n Cipher Text: %s", ptext, ctext);
        return 0;
    }
}


string cipher(string ptext, int k)
{
    string ctext = NULL;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(ptext); i < n; i++) {
        // check if lower / upper is true if yes then shift chars by k % 26 and append to ctext
        if (islower(ptext[i]))
        {
            ctext[i] = (ptext[i] + k - 96) % 26 + 96;
        }
        else if (isupper(ptext[i]))
        {
            ctext[i] = (ptext[i] + k - 65) % 26 + 65;
        } // else append as it is
        else
        {
            ctext[i] = ptext[i];
        }
    }
    return (ctext);
}
```

for inputs of Hi!. I want a output Ij!
I'm unable to figure out this error. please help.

Comment: What does `get_string` do? Does it allocate memory?

Comment: `string` in CS50 is `char *` That means there is no memory allocated yet. So assigning to `ctext[i]` in `cipher` is invalid.

Comment: Use a debugger and use singe step in your code. It will show you where the segment fault occurs.

Comment: Find out _where_ the crash happens, the [edit] your question and tell us. Also tell us what exactly your input is and how you invoke the program.

Comment: The whole `string` thing in cs50.h is crap and leads to misunderstandings such as this.

Comment: @jabberwocky edited the question. with debug my code is exiting at ctext1[i] = (ptext[i] + k1 - 65) % 26 + 65; with an input Hi!

Comment: Please never use magic numbers like 65 or 96. If you need a value of a character, type a single quote, then the character, then another single quote: `'A'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CS50** introduces a type `string` hiding a `char` pointer. This creates confusion as this `string` type is very different from what other languages name as such. Pointers are a fundamental concept that must be mastered to write programs in C.

The statement `ptext = get_string("Text:");` sets `ptext` to the pointer value returned by the function `get_string()` declared in `<cs50.h>`. This function allocates memory for an array of `char`, reads user input into this array, sets a null terminator (a byte with a zero value) at the end of the array and returns a pointer to the first element of this array.

For your program to work, you can either:

- modify the array in place, replacing each byte with its cipher value, or
- allocate another array and store the cipher values into it, appending a null terminator after them. You chose this approach, but did not allocate the array.

Note also these problems:

- the `for` loop validating the key string should be separate from the code calling the `cypher` function.
- you should use character values such as `'a'` and `'A'` instead of hard coding their ASCII values. It improves portability and readability.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *cipher(char *ptext, int k);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        char *key = argv[1];

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(key); i < n; i++) {
            if (isdigit(key[i]) == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        int k = atoi(key);
        char *ptext = get_string("Text:");
        char *ctext = cipher(ptext, k);

        printf("Plain Text: %s\nCipher Text: %s", ptext, ctext);
        free(ctext);
        return 0;
    }
}

char *cipher(char *ptext, int k) {
    int n = strlen(ptext);
    char *ctext = malloc(n + 1);  // allocate memory for the cipher string
    if (ctext == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        unsigned char pi = ptext[i];
        // check if lower / upper is true if yes then shift chars by k % 26 and append to ctext
        if (islower(pi))
        {
            // handle lowercase letter
            ctext[i] = (pi - 'a' + k) % 26 + 'a';
        }
        else if (isupper(pi))
        {
            // handle uppercase letter
            ctext[i] = (pi - 'A' + k) % 26 + 'A';
        }
        else
        {
            // else append as it is
            ctext[i] = pi;
        }
    }
    ctext[n] = '\0';  // set the null terminator
    return ctext;
}
```

Comment: this is awesome, I'm getting this as additional message post execution of the code. `free(): double free detected in tcache 2`.

Comment: @Vishruth: my bad, cs50 documentation says: *`get_string()` [...] stores string on heap, but library's destructor frees memory on program's exit* so `free(ptext)` is unwarranted.

Answer (score 0):

> with debug my code is exiting at
> `ctext1[i] = (ptext[i] + k1 - 65) % 26 + 65;`

You have not allocated any memory for your string. This is the cause of the segmentation fault because `ctext[i]` access an invalid memory address.

To solve that, you must allocate memory to `ctext`.